# How to upload a ImageView to webservice in android?

Tags: android, web-services

I have a Image view in xml as follows.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qrcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />
```

And in this imageview I am creating a qr code. And I want to send it to werservice.

```
public class GenerateQrcode extends ActivityGroup{
    String id;
    ImageView image;
     Bitmap bm;
     Button qrusers,qrinvites,qrback;
     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qrcode);

     image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrcode);
```

I have generated qr code using zxing library and assigned that qr code image to above imageview.

So inside image I have the qr code. How to send this image to webservice.

Comment: Did you search for this?

Comment: yes I searched but the tutorial are accessing the image from sd card. ,but I dont want to use sd card,coz I already have image in imageview and want upload it to server.

Comment: then save you image into sdcard and use that code...

Answer (score 0):

Try following example

```
 public void upload(String filepath) throws IOException
 {
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url");
 File file = new File(filepath);
 MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
 ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
 mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile); 
 httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
 System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
         // check the response and do what is required
  }
```

it may help you.

Comment: My image is not in sd card. HOw to put the image in filepath?

Comment: First you have to save the image to the temporary folder in sdcard and then get the file path.Start the upload .Using AsynkTask will be preferable for good performance.

Answer (score 0):

First get bitmap out of imageview by :

```
Bitmap bitmap=image.getDrawingCache()
```

Now call following function in `AsyncTask`:

```
 public void executeMultipartPost(Bitmap bm) throws Exception {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("<YourURL>");//<----------URL
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "forest.jpg");
            // File file= new File("/mnt/sdcard/forest.png");
            // FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("uploaded", bab);
            reqEntity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody("sfsdfsdf"));
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
            System.out.println("Response: " + s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception here
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image view to a Bitmap file ,

```
image.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmp = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

Convert this to a byte array

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

send this byteArray through your webservice

Comment: Can you please code it here how to send this bytearray to webservice?

Comment: what kind of webservice are you using?

Comment: FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("what to add here?");

Comment: File someFile = new File("fileName");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
        fos.write(byteArray);//byte array created from imageview
        fos.flush();
        fos.close(); finally,FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(someFile);